# Swift Draw a route for an array of value

Tags: arrays, swift, mapkit, overlay, polyline

Hi I have an array like this route = [[latitude,longitude],[latitude,longitude]...]. 
I should draw a line that follows the arrays coordinates. I tried with this function:

```
 func addPolylineToMap(locations: [CLLocation]){
    var coordinates = locations.map({ (location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        return location.coordinate})
    var countLocations = locations.count
    let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count)
    mapView.addOverlay(geodesic)
}
```

and calling the function giving it the array route:

```
addPolylineToMap(locations: route as! [CLLocation])
```

but compiler gives me the error `ambiguous use of 'init(coordinates:count:)'`

Anyway I'm not so sure it could work. 
Could someone explain me how to do it better ?

P.S.

ROUTE

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    var userLatitude = (userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    var userLongitude = (userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    userMoves = [(userLatitude),(userLongitude)]
```

route is an array created appending user moves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove that `&`. In Swift 3:

```
func addPolylineToMap(locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let coordinates = locations.map { $0.coordinate }
    let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
    mapView.add(geodesic)
}
```

Or in Swift 2:

```
func addPolylineToMap(locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let coordinates = locations.map { $0.coordinate }
    let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
    mapView.addOverlay(geodesic)
}
```

Comment: Fine, that part of code is working now thank you but I receive a new error on: addPolylineToMap(locations: route as! [CLLocation])
It says: "thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: CONSOLE OUTPUT: Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x10a665040) to 'CLLocation' (0x10a35f388).

Comment: Look at the contents. I bet they're not `CLLocation` objects. But this is all a separate question. Do some diagnostics and figure out how you built `route`. If you're still having problems, post a separate question on that topic.

Comment: On the answer there is how I created route

Comment: Well, `userMoves` is apparently an array with numeric values of latitudes and longitudes, not `CLLocation` objects. Why don't you just add the `userLocation` object to your array? It's a `CLLocation` object already. Also, you obviously need a couple of `CLLocation` objects in that array in order to draw a geodesic line between two different locations. You can't draw a geodesic line with only one location.

Comment: sorry Rob, I understand the problem of CLLocation and I would resolve it, but I don't understand the second part of the message can't I draw a route the follows the coordinates of the array ?

Comment: The code in your comment showed code that build an array with a single location's coordinate. You can't draw a line with only one coordinate. Now, if you're appending that to an existing array that has some previous coordinate(s), then that's fine. You simply have more than more than one location to draw lines between them. Perhaps you had other code which you didn't share with us, so that's fine. But you showed me code that built an array with a single latitude and longitude, so my comment was based upon that.

Comment: I choose it as best answer but I can't vote It, thank you